# Bash script, comparing numbers

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

Is it possible to compare `$ip_choice` with a number without setting it before?

```
#!/bin/bash
ip_choice=999
while ! (( $ip_choice <= 233 ))
  do 
    read -p "Enter a valid IP (1-256): " ip_choice
  done
```

It work's like that - only I want to know if there is a more elegant possibility :-).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r -p "Enter a valid IP (1-256): " ip_choice; do
     (( ip_choice >= 1 && ip_choice <= 256 )) && break
done    
echo "${ip_choice}"
```

---

```
$ ./t.sh
Enter a valid IP (1-256): -1
Enter a valid IP (1-256): 0
Enter a valid IP (1-256): 257
Enter a valid IP (1-256): abc
Enter a valid IP (1-256): 20
20
```

Answer (score 5):

You could make use of `until`:

```
until ((ip_choice >=1 && ip_choice <= 256)); do
  read -p "Enter a valid IP (1-256): " ip_choice;
done
```

Quoting from `help until`:

> `until: until COMMANDS; do COMMANDS; done`
>
> ```
> Execute commands as long as a test does not succeed.
>
> Expand and execute COMMANDS as long as the final command in the
> `until' COMMANDS has an exit status which is not zero.
>
> Exit Status:
> Returns the status of the last command executed.
> ```

For example:

```
$ until ((ip_choice >=1 && ip_choice <= 256)); do
>   read -p "Enter a valid IP (1-256): " ip_choice;
> done
Enter a valid IP (1-256): 0
Enter a valid IP (1-256): 298
Enter a valid IP (1-256): 242
```